# Order between surfaces greater or equal than one is an equivalence relation.

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that the relation $\sim$ between regular surfaces with a common point $p$ given by $S_1 \sim S_2$ iff $S_1, S_2$ have contact of order $\geq1$, is an equivalence relation.

We say that $S_1,S_2$ have contact of order $\geq1$ if there exist parametrizations $\mathbf{x}(u,v), \mathbf{y}(u,v)$ with the same domain, such that $\mathbf{x}_u=\mathbf{y}_u$ and $\mathbf{x}_v=\mathbf{y}_v$ at $p$.

Clearly, $\sim$ is reflexive and symmetric.

I have tried to prove that $\sim$ is transitive. Let me show you what I have tried.

Let $S_1,S_2,S_3$ be regular surfaces with a common point $p$ and suppose that $S_1 \sim S_2$ and $S_2 \sim S_3$.

As $S_1 \sim S_2$, it follows that exists 
parametrizations $\mathbf{x}(u,v), \mathbf{y}(u,v)$ with the same domain, of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, such that $\mathbf{x}_u=\mathbf{y}_u$ and $\mathbf{x}_v=\mathbf{y}_v$ at $p$.

Similarly, as $S_2 \sim S_3$, it follows that exists 
parametrizations $\mathbf{s}(u,v), \mathbf{t}(u,v)$ with the same domain, of $S_2$ and $S_3$, respectively, such that $\mathbf{s}_u=\mathbf{t}_u$ and $\mathbf{s}_v=\mathbf{t}_v$ at $p$.

I want to prove that $\mathbf{y}_u=\mathbf{s}_u$ in order to conclude that $\mathbf{x}_u=\mathbf{t}_u$ but I don't have any ideas. I think that I need to use a change of coordinates between the domain of $\mathbf{y}$ and the domain of $\mathbf{s}$ but I can't make it concrete.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you needn't have the independent variables $(u,v)$ lining up, but it doesn't matter. I think you should have parametrizations $\mathbf s(u',v')$ and $\mathbf t(u',v')$. But the fact that $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf s$ parametrize (by restriction) the same domain in $S_2$ means that $(u',v') = \phi(u,v)$ for some diffeomorphism $\phi$ and so you can reduce to the case that $(u',v') = (u,v)$ by composing $\mathbf s$ and $\mathbf t$ with $\phi$.

The vectors $\mathbf y_u,\mathbf y_v$ and the vectors $\mathbf s_u,\mathbf s_v$ each form a basis for the tangent space of $S_2$ at $p$. So $\mathbf y_u = a_{11}\mathbf s_u + a_{21}\mathbf s_v$ and $\mathbf y_v = a_{12}\mathbf s_u + a_{22}\mathbf s_v$ for some invertible matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$. So consider $\tilde{\mathbf s} = \mathbf s\circ A$ and check that this is the right parametrization to use for $S_2$. Make $\tilde{\mathbf t}$ correspondingly.